# WP7 Button with detailed desctiption

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

What is best way to create a button like this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SLjJ.png]

Button contains action and description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will come very close

```
 <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20" Background="Black">
            <Button.Content>
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Margin="5">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="3">primary text</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray"
                                   Margin="3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="primary text" />
        <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum..." />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```